# My Powershell script is not explicitly calling for any specific resources but I am getting "ErrorCode: TargetResourceNotFound" error

Tags: azure, powershell

My Powershell script is not explicitly calling for any specific resources but I am getting "ErrorCode: TargetResourceNotFound" error. I have attached the error in the image. What am I missing?

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*-NonProd"}
foreach ($sub in $subs)
{
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
$RGs = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*Infra"} 
foreach ($RG in $RGs)
{
$NetworkWatchers = Get-AzNetworkWatcher
$NSGs = (Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup).Id 
foreach ($NSG in $NSGs)
{
       foreach ($NetworkWatcher in $NetworkWatchers)
{ 
       $Status = Get-AzNetworkWatcherFlowLogStatus -NetworkWatcherName $NetworkWatcher.Name 
ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName -TargetResourceId $NSG -Verbose
}
     if (($Status).Enabled -eq $true)
{
     Write-Output  "$NSG in $(($sub).Name) has FlowLogs Enabled" | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\Users\user1\downloads\Output.txt'  -Verbose -Append
}
     if (($Status).Enabled -ne $true)
{ 
    Write-Output  "$NSG in $(($sub).Name) does not have FlowLogs Enabled" | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\Users\user1\downloads\Output.txt'  -Verbose -Append 
   }
  }
 }
}

enter code here
```

Error Attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Network Watchers are usually in a hidden resource group, and perhaps you are trying to find one in one of the available RGs. Try omitting the RG factor and use

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*-NonProd" }
foreach ($sub in $subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    $NetworkWatchers = Get-AzNetworkWatcher
    $NSGs = (Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup).Id 
    foreach ($NSG in $NSGs) {
        foreach ($NetworkWatcher in $NetworkWatchers) { 
 
            $Status = Get-AzNetworkWatcherFlowLogStatus -NetworkWatcher $NetworkWatcher -TargetResourceId $NSG -Verbose
        }
        if (($Status).Enabled -eq $true) {
            Write-Output  "$NSG in $(($sub).Name) has FlowLogs Enabled" | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\Users\user1\downloads\Output.txt'  -Verbose -Append
        }
        if (($Status).Enabled -ne $true) { 
            Write-Output  "$NSG in $(($sub).Name) does not have FlowLogs Enabled" | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\Users\user1\downloads\Output.txt'  -Verbose -Append 
        }
    }
   
}
```

I am able to get all flow logs configuration status.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error **`TargetResourceNotFound`** usually occurs if you are passing invalid resource group name or subscription name.

To confirm whether the resource group or subscription exists, execute the below code lines separately like below:

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*-name"}
$subs

$RGs = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*name"} 
$RGs
```

[image]

The error states that Target resource identifier `/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/***  not found in the region westeurope`. Cross-verify whether the Network Watcher exists.

***I am able to get the status of the Network Watcher successfully when I passed valid subscription and Resource group like below:***

If the error still persists, try excluding the **`$RGs = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*name"}`** and execute.

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/NcS3dvH.png)]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your assistance.
I got it working by changing -NetworkWatcherName $NetworkWatcher.Name to -NetworkWatcherName $NetworkWatcher.ResourceGroupName

```
    foreach ($NSG in $NSGs)
    {
        # $NSG.Id
        # $NSGid = $NSG.Id
        foreach ($NetworkWatcher in $NetworkWatchers)
        { 
            $Status = Get-AzNetworkWatcherFlowLogStatus -NetworkWatcherName $NetworkWatcher.ResourceGroupName -ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName -TargetResourceId $NSG -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if (($Status).Enabled -eq $true)
            {
               Write-Output  "$NSG in $(($sub).Name) has FlowLogs Enabled" | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\Users\A240379\downloads\OutEnabled.csv'  -Verbose -Append

            }
            if (($Status).Enabled -ne $true)
            { 
                Write-Output  "$NSG in $(($sub).Name) does not have FlowLogs Enabled" | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\Users\A240379\downloads\OutNotEnabled.csv'  -Verbose -Append 

            }

        }

    }
```